Typescript upgrade: Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations
I'm trying to upgrade my mono-repo having 27 packages from Node 16.x to Node 18.x (and later to a newer version). The repo is managed by PNPM package manager also being updated from 6.x to 7.x.
Problem: I oberserved a strange behaviour for which I'm seeking advise on how to handle this. The original output folder changed from ./dist to .dist/lib causing me a lot of trouble whenever the package is used by other packages.
Example: one package @myapp/utils is used in other packages has a folder structure like this. I added the full package.json and tsconfig.json code at the bottom.
/common/utils
/common/utils/lib/
/common/utils/lib/uid
/common/utils/lib/uid/index.ts
/common/utils/lib/uid/uid.factory.ts

Before the upgrade
Using pnpm 6.32.2 and nodejs 16.13.0 the output folder structure of the build command rimraf dist && tsc was this:
/common/utils
/common/utils/dist/
/common/utils/dist/uid
/common/utils/dist/uid/index.d.ts
/common/utils/dist/uid/index.js
/common/utils/dist/uid/uid.factory.d.ts
/common/utils/dist/uid/uid.factory.js
/common/utils/dist/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo

The package.json contains the following:
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/node": "~20.10.5",
  "typescript": "~5.3.3"
}

The tsconfig.json contains the following:
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./lib",
    }

Problem after the upgrade
Using pnpm 7.0.0 and nodejs 18.0.0 the output folder structure of the build command rimraf dist && tsc slightly changed to ./dist/lib while having the ./dist/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo at the correct place.
/common/utils
/common/utils/dist/
/common/utils/dist/lib
/common/utils/dist/lib/uid
/common/utils/dist/lib/uid/index.d.ts
/common/utils/dist/lib/uid/index.js
/common/utils/dist/lib/uid/uid.factory.d.ts
/common/utils/dist/lib/uid/uid.factory.js
/common/utils/dist/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo

This caused problems in another package A that uses the @myapp/utils package.

Cannot find module '@myapp/utils' or its corresponding type declarations.

The package.json of package A contains this:
  "dependencies": {
    "@myapp/utils": "workspace:0.5.0"
  },
  "dependencieMeta": {
    "@myapp/utils": {
      "injected": true
    }
  },

Workaround A
In package A I had to add the paths configuration to its tsconfig.json like this:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@myapp/utils": ["../utils/dist"]
    }
  }
}

The problem I'm having with this is (a) that other utility packages that are build into ./build are not having this issue. (b) in every source code file that uses @myapp/utils I had to change the import statement like adding the /lib suffix.
import { uid } from "@myapp/utils/lib";

Question: Is there a better way to handle this instead of changing all references in code and tsconfig.json?
Workaround B
I slightly modified the tsconfig.json of @myapp/utils by adding a rootUrl:
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./lib",
        "rootUrl": "./lib"
    },

This corrected the output folder structure and (c) there was no need to add any paths configurations to other packages (d) nor modifying any source code using that package.
Side effect: But it caused (c) the tsconfig.tsbuildinfo file being one level higher outside the actual build ./dist folder thus causing (d) incremental build problems in the workspace.
Question: I'm not happy with workaround A nor B. Any furthr idea?
Appendix: Source Code
tsconfig.json of /common/utils before and after the upgrade:
{
    "extends": "./node_modules/gts/tsconfig-google.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es2018",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "baseUrl": "./lib",
        "incremental": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "types": [
            "jest",
            "node"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "lib/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}

package.json of /common/utils before the upgrade:
{
  "name": "@myapp/utils",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "description": "utility types",
  "author": "tba",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "See LICENSE.md in root folder",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "gts check lib/**/*.ts",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "lint:fix": "gts fix lib/**/*.ts",
    "prepare": "pnpm build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "neverthrow": "6.1.0",
    "tslib": "2.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "29.5.11",
    "@types/node": "~20.10.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "6.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "6.15.0",
    "eslint": "8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "gts": "5.2.0",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.1",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/lib"
    ],
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": [
        "ts-jest",
        {
          "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../../../coverage",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      ".interface.ts$",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}

package.json of /common/utils after the upgrade:
{
  "name": "@myapp/utils",
  "version": "0.5.0",
  "description": "utility types",
  "author": "tba",
  "private": true,
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "See LICENSE.md in root folder",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "gts check lib/**/*.ts",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "lint:fix": "gts fix lib/**/*.ts",
    "prepare": "pnpm build"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "neverthrow": "8.1.1",
    "tslib": "2.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "29.5.3",
    "@types/node": "~22.10.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "8.18.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "8.18.2",
    "eslint": "9.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.1.0",
    "gts": "6.0.2",
    "jest": "29.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^6.0.1",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "typescript": "~5.7.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": ".",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/lib"
    ],
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": [
        "ts-jest",
        {
          "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json"
        }
      ]
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../../../coverage",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      ".interface.ts$",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}


Probably try to not update node and pnpm at once to minimize the amount of moving parts? Considering that ts versions didn't change,probablu pnpm has a breaking change regarding monorepos

PNPM is not the problem. I successfully updated it to 8.15.7 on a different branch without touching Node.

The problem was that the Typescript compiler (TSC) resolves the paths a bit differently now. To ensure it gets the correct path information, I had to modify the tsconfig.json as follows:
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "rootDir": "./lib",
        "baseUrl": "./lib",
        "tsBuildInfoFile": "./dist/tsconfig.tsbuildinfo",

The rootDir tells TSC from which folder to create the folder structure in the outDir. The tsBuildInfoFile ensures that the file is in the outDir and correctly handled on rebuild.
PS: In Node 18.17.0 this behaviour was gone and the build behaved normally even without those changes.
